# Numpy argmax. How to compute both max and argmax?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to get max and argmax by one stroke ?

```
import numpy as np
a=[0,0,1,0]
maximum=max(a)
index=np.argmax(a)
```

Is there a fastest way to do it, with something like:

```
[maximum,index]=function(a)
```

Comment: There are times `pytorch` is more elegant than `numpy`: `torch.tensor([0,0,1,0]).max(0)` gives `torch.return_types.max(values=tensor(1),indices=tensor(2))`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Maybe something like this is faster...

```
index = np.argmax(a)
maximum = a[index]
```

Comment: Good point on saving the calculation time, however, if the original argmax call were to sort a 2D array on the second axis, then the second statement would likely throw an error.

Comment: You could recover it by using unravel_index (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html)